# SQL split string and find if token exists in other table

Tags: mysql, sql, split

Having a table T1 contains

| TITLE |
| --- |
| age 5 alton john live |
| show must go on |

Having a table T2 contains

| NAME. | DESCRIPTION |
| --- | --- |
| John Bo | alton for kids |
| Alton | show age kids |

I would like to split TITLE (T1) and check if at list one token exists in DESCRIPTION (T2) and return TITLE and DESCRIPTION

Expected Output:

| TITLE | DESCRIPTION |
| --- | --- |
| age 5 alton john live. | alton for kids |
| age 5 alton john live. | show age kids |
| show must go on | show age kids |

Comment: What DBMS are you using?

Comment: @lemon mySql DBMS

Comment: I don't think MySQL has any built-in way to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Main problem here is to wrangle table t1 to associate each "*TITLE*" value to each sequence of characters separated by space. Then you can match your wrangled table with your t2 table on a regex pattern. May require quite a bit of time as doing a join on such string condition is not very efficient, but it works.

You can generate that association with a [recursive query](https://dev.mysql.com/worklog/task/?id=3634), that exploits [`SUBSTRING_INDEX`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index) to retrieve last word of "*TITLE*" and a numerical index that is decreased. Recursion would stop once that numerical index reaches 0.

```
WITH RECURSIVE cte AS (
    SELECT TITLE, 
           LENGTH(TITLE)-LENGTH(REPLACE(TITLE,' ','')) AS num_words,
           SUBSTRING_INDEX(
               SUBSTRING_INDEX(TITLE, ' ', 
                               LENGTH(TITLE)-
                               LENGTH(REPLACE(TITLE,' ',''))+1
               ), ' ', -1) AS word
    FROM t1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT TITLE,
           num_words - 1 AS num_words,
           SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(TITLE, ' ', num_words), ' ', -1)
    FROM cte
    WHERE num_words > 0
)
SELECT *
FROM       cte
INNER JOIN t2
        ON t2.DESCRIPTION REGEXP CONCAT('( |^)', cte.word, '( |$)')
```

Check the demo [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/cCSzFmHfCsFtzkjADZiFJH/0).

**Assumption**: your sentences have no punctuation, and every word is separated by a space character.

Comment: Thank you. I will test it now. Just wondering what is num_words since it is zero in 2 rows?

Comment: "*Num_words*" is a value that begins with the total number of words in each sentence, then at each iteration it gets decreased. It allows to get the fifth, fourth, third... word at each iteration. Check the linked demo at the bottom of the answer, also I'd recommend to see intermediate steps, like the output of the cte only (`WITH RECURSIVE cte AS (....) SELECT * FROM cte`).

Comment: How could I change the query in order to return bi-gram and not a single word?

Comment: Craft an example output of what you mean for one row.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74790923/sql-compose-bi-gram-and-search-if-exists-in-other-table