# SQL compose bi-gram and search if exists in other table

Tags: mysql, sql, split, n-gram

In SQL, having a table T1 contains

| TITLE |
| --- |
| age 5 alton john live |
| show must go on |

Having a table T2 contains

| NAME. | DESCRIPTION |
| --- | --- |
| John Bo | altonjohn for kids |
| Alton | show age5 mustgo kids |

I would like to finding bigrams (pairs of consecutive words) in TITLE (T1) and check if at list 1 bigram exists in DESCRIPTION (T2) and return TITLE, DESCRIPTION & the BI-GRAM

Expected Output:

| TITLE | DESCRIPTION | . BIGRAM |
| --- | --- | --- |
| age 5 alton john live. | altonjohn for kids. | . altonjohn |
| age 5 alton john live. | show age5 mustgo kids | . age5 |
| show must go on | show age5 mustgo kids | . mustgo |

Comment: Shouldn't there be a space between words of the same bigram (in the "*DESCRIPTION*" field)? @userit1985

Comment: @lemon no. we want to find those bigrams. this is an example. I am looking to find  words like offwhite that appear also as off-white or off white. cocacola | coca-cola | coca cola.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A slight variation of the [previous query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74771979/sql-split-string-and-find-if-token-exists-in-other-table#74771979) should do this easily:

```
WITH RECURSIVE cte AS (
    SELECT TITLE, 
           LENGTH(TITLE)-LENGTH(REPLACE(TITLE,' ','')) AS num_bigrams,
           SUBSTRING_INDEX(
               SUBSTRING_INDEX(TITLE, ' ', 
                               LENGTH(TITLE)-LENGTH(REPLACE(TITLE,' ',''))+1
               ), ' ', -2) AS bigram
    FROM t1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT TITLE,
           num_bigrams - 1 AS num_bigrams,
           SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(TITLE, ' ', num_bigrams), ' ', -2)
    FROM cte
    WHERE num_bigrams > 1
)
SELECT TITLE, DESCRIPTION, bigram
FROM       cte
INNER JOIN t2
        ON t2.DESCRIPTION REGEXP CONCAT('( |^)', cte.bigram, '( |$)')
```

Differences are:

- Using -2 in the `SUBSTRING_INDEX` function, to recover the last two words instead of the last one [you can generalize on this for trigrams and others too], both for the base and the recursive step of the recursion.
- Getting the recursion to end 1 step earlier, cause bigrams will take 2 words at a time, hence changing the recursion ending condition to `WHERE num_bigrams > 1` instead of `WHERE num_bigrams > 0`.

Check the demo [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/cCSzFmHfCsFtzkjADZiFJH/1).

Note: if you want to remove the middle space from the bigram, you just need to add a REPLACE function that removes that extra space.